# Delete schema from schema registry

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-schema-registry

I know that the documentation of Confluent says that the schemas cannot be deleted in case of some clueless producer.

BUT I still would like to know if there is any way of deleting a schema from the schema registry, not just deleting a specific schema version of a subject, deleting also the schema ID at all.

Comment: The ID is stored as part of any given message, not just the registry.... A message cannot be deleted, only expired. Deleting a version in the registry is still going to leave behind any produced messages containing that ID

Comment: so there is no way to delete a schema ID to prevent producers to use a old schema ID?

Comment: The problem isn't really the producers... If you deleted an ID **after** the producer already sent the message (which you can't really prevent except one config), you'd get a `404: schema ID not found`, causing the consumer to crash

Answer (score 1):

You cannot delete the schema directly, rather you have to delete the subject attached to the schema.

You access schema registry url like below to see all the schemas.

```
https://<schemaregistryurl:port/schemas
```

So, if your topic name is mytopic, then you must see two schemas in the schema registry with subject named "mytopic-key" and "mytopic-value". Below is an example schema value in "mytopic-value"

```
{
"subject": "mytopic-value",
"version": 1,
"id": 100423,
"schema": "{"type":"record","name":"User","fields":[{"name":"username","type":"string"},{"name":"phone","type":"long"},{"name":"age","type":"int"}]}"
}
```

Now if you want to delete this schema, you have to delete the subject.
All the subjects are listed on `https://<schemaregistryurl:port/subjects`

Soft Delete of all schemas regiseterd against the subject

```
curl -u username:password -X DELETE http://localhost:8081/subjects/mytopic-value
```

To hard delete you have to pass `?permanent=true`

More options for deletions like, selective versions, latest version can be found on the related documentation at https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/schema-deletion-guidelines.html